# How to find two instance of beyond compare merge tool window

Tags: java

How can I find the two instances of beyond compare window?

There should be only one window opened at a time. How can I identify it using Java? I tried something like below, but it didn't work.

```
if(processor(start).command.size() > 1){return false;}
```

Comment: You're clearly using a application library of some sort - which is it?  What are those "processor", "command", etc classes/types....  also please post a complete example; there's not enough here to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to execute beyond compare exe file. c/beyondcompare/beyond.exe. I am trying to run one instance of .exe at a  time. i,e i need only one window to be open at a time.